# Pause Kinect Camera - Possible error in SDK reguarding event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I'm in the process of converting my **Microsoft SDK Beta** code to the **Microsoft SDK Official Release** that was released February 2012.

I added a generic `PauseKinect()` to pause the Kinect. My pause will really only remove the event handler that updated the image

#### Pros:

- No Reinitialization (30+ second wait time)

#### Cons:

- Kinect still processing images

### Pause Method (Color Only)

```
internal void PauseColorImage(bool isPaused)
{
    if (isPaused)
    {
        _Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
        //_Kinect.ColorStream.Disable();
    }

    else
    {
        _Kinect.ColorFrameReady += ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
        //_Kinect.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
    }
}
```

#### PROBLEM:

Even though I'm removing the event why is it still getting triggered?

#### NOTE:

Also when I pause the color image I'm also pausing the depth and skeleton in their object.

#### SIDE NOTE:

If I uncomment my code it works fine, but then it'll take forever to reinitialize which is **not** what I want to do.

#### MS in Reflector

```
public void AddHandler(EventHandler<T> originalHandler)
{
    if (originalHandler != null)
    {
        this._actualHandlers.Add(new ContextHandlerPair<T, T>(originalHandler, SynchronizationContext.Current));
    }
}

public void RemoveHandler(EventHandler<T> originalHandler)
{
    SynchronizationContext current = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    ContextHandlerPair<T, T> item = null;
    foreach (ContextHandlerPair<T, T> pair2 in this._actualHandlers)
    {
        EventHandler<T> handler = pair2.Handler;
        SynchronizationContext context = pair2.Context;
        if ((current == context) && (handler == originalHandler))
        {
            item = pair2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (item != null)
    {
        this._actualHandlers.Remove(item);
    }
}


public void Invoke(object sender, T e)
{
    if (this.HasHandlers)
    {
        ContextHandlerPair<T, T>[] array = new ContextHandlerPair<T, T>[this._actualHandlers.Count];
        this._actualHandlers.CopyTo(array);
        foreach (ContextHandlerPair<T, T> pair in array)
        {
            EventHandler<T> handler = pair.Handler;
            SynchronizationContext context = pair.Context;
            if (context == null)
            {
                handler(sender, e);
            }
            else if (this._method == ContextSynchronizationMethod<T>.Post)
            {
                context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(this.SendOrPostDelegate), new ContextEventHandlerArgsWrapper<T, T>(handler, sender, e));
            }
            else if (this._method == ContextSynchronizationMethod<T>.Send)
            {
               context.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(this.SendOrPostDelegate), new ContextEventHandlerArgsWrapper<T, T>(handler, sender, e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe decompile the class containing `ColorFrameReady` event and see what's going on?

Comment: I have been in Reflector. I believe it has to do with how Microsoft Removes it's event handler. I can't tell for sure because I cant step through Microsoft dll without a pdb file

Comment: 1. This link has some info on how to configure to use MS symbol server http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503 2. Sometime it is possible to decompile the code with reflector than compile it again with VS. Then you'll have all the required symbols. 3. I would very carefully inspect my code to completely exclude the possibility of adding handler more than once (it happened to me); then removing the handler once does not stop the handler from execution.

Comment: My codes out of the question (as far as I know) I even tried this in the sample code the Microsoft provided. Ill look into the other 2

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, are you calling PauseKinect(false) multiple times and therefore hooking the event multiple times?

Comment: No offense but I have to say...Yea I'm not a moron. I can do the following any nothing happens...

_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;
_Kinect.ColorFrameReady -= ColorFrameReadyEventHandler;

Comment: how does MS remove the event handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting an identical question on the Microsoft forum and talking to multiple Microsoft representatives they basically said the only way to do a "pause" is to enable/disable the streams (uncomment my comments). Without saying it straight forward its a bug in the SDK. They are going to talk to the people in the development team and try to fix the issue in future releases.

#### EDIT

In the May 2012 Release it is STILL not fixed. Thanks Microsoft!